# Is possible to have alternate table rows in another color in org-mode tables?

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I would want something like this, for some specific tables with many rows (so columns are easier to read):

[image]

I know about [stripes mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/StripesMode) (and sometimes I resort to using it), but that changes format for the whole buffer, not just one table in it (the image below was taken using a locally modified version of stripes.el, btw)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package [stripe-buffer](https://github.com/sabof/stripe-buffer) defines a minor mode (`stripe-table-mode`) for that.